# java HttpClient-4.1.2 jar

Tags: java, exception, verifyerror

i am using httpclient-4.1.2 jar file in my project,and write code:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

but its throwing an exception

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient, method: setDefaultHttpParams signature: (Lorg/apache/http/params/HttpParams;)V) Incompatible argument to function

Answer (score 1):

You have to have the other jars for the httpclient as well (httpcore for example, a lots of the apache commons as well).

Answer (score 1):

The parameter "HttpParams" is in fact an interface which needs to be sent as parameter to `setDefaultHttpParams`.

Are you constructing this and is it being sent? In order to send it, you need to have some other jar, and this is the problem.

Comment: ,i am constructing this..plz give me hint in order to set the parameter

Comment: Interface:    http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/params/HttpParams.html